# Jquery dotdotdot ellipsis spacing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, ellipsis

I am running in to an issue where if there is no ellipsis there is no space between the ellipsis text and the text following it. I couldn't find an answer for this on stackoverflow nor google search.

I am currently using jquery dotdotdot plugin to put an ellipsis after certain characters in my paragraph.
My code structure looks like this:

```
<div class="ellipsis">
   <p> this is some text. this is some text. this is some text. </p>
   <asp:Literal id="litLearn" runat="server" Text="Read More" />
</div>
```

and the output looks like this:
    this is some text. this is some... Read More.

The issue here is if my text is not long enough then there is no ellipsis and there is no spacing between my text in the

tag and Read More text so the output looks like this:
this is some textRead More.

I can put a space in my code itself in Read More text but the issue is I have to do it on tons of pages in the site so I wanted to see if there is a css or jquery way of doing it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

add this to your `p` element as a CSS property.

Comment: This didn't work. I added that style to the p tag and nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use:

```
<p> this is some text. this is some text. this is some text.&nbsp;</p>
```

And:

```
$(".ellipsis").dotdotdot({
   lastCharacter: {
      //just remove the empty space in the array so that it wont get removed
      remove: [ ',', ';', '.', '!', '?' ]
   }
});
```